# find control base on function in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a function that is linked to a control. If I double click the control the editor will go to the function below.

My question is if I have function below and I know it is linked to a control, is there shortcut to find this control on the screen ?
In some situations there are to many controls and indicators on screen, it is difficult to search all the controls and indicator names in controls and indicator list.

```
private void MOVE_START_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)        
{
}
```

Comment: please clarify question looks like maze to me !! :)

Comment: Do you mean you would like to find which button on a winform is attached to this event handler?

Comment: Not that I know of. One could conceivably create a VS addon that added something like a "Go to referenced control" context menu item that would bring up the designer and select the control. Multiple controls could reference the same event handler, in which case you'd need to pick which one to go to.

Answer (score 4):

(I assume you want to find the control *in the designer*, not *at runtime*).

You can easily find the control(s) that use this handler by right-clicking the `MOVE_START_Click` method and selecting "Find All References". It should show something like:

```
Form1.Designer.cs - (1, 1): button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(MOVE_START_Click);
```

Then in the designer, just above the properties window, you can select that control from the combobox:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No there is no short cut that gets automatically created.

One thing you could do is have the form with all of the controls on it listen for key down events. First you have to set the KeyPreview property on the form to true then add a KeyDown event listener to the form. After that you can listen for specific hot-keys to be pressed like `ctrl-f`

```
private void form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.F && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control)
    {
        // Set the control you want to map to the hotkey as active here
        myControl.Focus()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, i want to find control in designer, not run time, in the designer i can select control in combobox, but i have a lot of controls and indicator, it is time consuming to go through one by one to find the right one.I am new to C#, i want to find the shortcut, if it exists. Thanks

Comment: Ah I missed that I guess. Well the above answer is good but I would also suggest looking at the document outline window as well. You can bring up it up under View --> Other Windows --> Document Outline 

This will show a hierarchical list of all the controls on the form by name which can be helpful as well.